# How to change URL path from www.website.com/v1 to www.website.com in Joomla

Tags: url, joomla, reroute

Im new in Joomla. I have setup joomla in my domain. However, the URL become www.website.com/joom3. Is there a way to retain joom3 folder but URL still display www.website.com? Therefore, when user key in www.website.com it will not display www.website.com/joom3

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have on the server Joomla is installed in root and in the directory /joom3. To ensure that we could access the site without specifying this directory should be placed in the root of the file server .htaccess with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^joom3(/?|/.+)$ /joom3%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Thus it is necessary not to forget to remove the /joom3 from the value of the variable $mosConfig_live_site in the configuration file Joomla.